# Homepage redirect using .htaccess

Tags: html, css, .htaccess

Using the `.htaccess` file how do I get my url to appear as `www.example.com` instead of `www.example.com/index.html`?

Comment: Did you search for ".htaccess index.html" on this site before asking this question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use that

```
# This allows you to redirect index.html to a specific subfolder
Redirect /index.html http://example.com/
```

or

```
# Provide Specific Index Page (Set the default handler)
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

> Carfully add that to .htaccess

Comment: My issue seems to be as follows, I can only get one or the other.  I would like the site to load the index at .com/, however if when I can get that to work I can't have other files load without .html